# menu toogle button not working in bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

In `bootstrap 4` when the header becomes responsive the breadcrumb button not working as it is.

I have included the `Bootstrap 4` `CSS` and bootstrap 4 `js`

please help me fix the issue

**Code:**

```css
.navbar {
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
  <div class="container nopadding">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          logo
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault"
        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto ">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">HOME <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a>SERVICES</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a>SUPPORT</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a>TECHNOLOGY</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
</nav>
    
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**Image:**
[image: screenshot after clicking breadcrumb]

Answer (score 1):

Check you error in console `Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery. jQuery must be included before Bootstrap's JavaScript.`

add jquery library before the bootstrap js

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
    <div class="container nopadding">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            logo
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault"
            aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto ">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">HOME <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a>SERVICES</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a>SUPPORT</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a>TECHNOLOGY</a>
                </li>

            </ul>

        </div>

    </div>

</nav>

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: i have added jquery.min and popper js

Comment: your code snippet is working now, recheck your code.